# Installing custom php extension does not show in phpinfo() even though ini file calls it

Tags: php, php-extension, php-ini, libpuzzle

I used to have this extension running before my reinstall of php.  phpinfo() shows my ini file is located at /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini

In the php.ini file I have:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/libpuzzle.so
```

The error.log shows:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> 'libpuzzle.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/libpuzzle.so
> (/usr/lib/php/20190902/libpuzzle.so: cannot open shared object file:
> No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/libpuzzle.so.so
> (/usr/lib/php/20190902/libpuzzle.so.so: cannot open shared object
> file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

I don't know why but in the log it says: libpuzzle.so.so. So I also created a libpuzzle.so.so in addition to libpuzzle.so. Restarted Apache and still, phpinfo will not show libpuzzle nor does libpuzzle work. Libpizzle required the GD library and I have the gd library installed and enabled. I verified the file exists and the permissions are root:root 644 just like all the other extension.

php -m does not show it as loaded either.

I am lost now and don't know where to look to get this up and running.  Any help on what to do next?

Comment: I got it to work. I used phpize for php 7.0  in the build process of the extension. phpize  I have php7.4 now so i installed phpize for 7.4, rebuilt the extension and it works. But still does not make sense because the extension so file was where it was supposed to be. I would still like an explanation to why I am wrong. Anyone?

Comment: "No such file or directory" is pretty clear. I usually found it is correct, even after having been absolutely convinced of the opposite at first ;-)

Comment: I ran into this problem and if I remember correctly, I was trying to install a 32-bit extension instead of a 64-bit, or possibly a windows NTS in a TS environment. Anyway, the error message was deceptive because the file existed, it was just the wrong type.

Comment: I mean, in all my 99 years of working with Ubuntu and other OS systems... if I can see it with ls -la, I can move it, and set permissions... the file is really there. haha. I think Chris Haas might be on to something there. I am on a 64bit system and thats where I compiled it so I assume it is 64bit. I dont know how to find out more and I assume I would a get a different error like invalid extension or something